# App is crashing without compile errors (xxx has stopped)

Tags: android, android-studio

The app worked just fine using `Nexus S5` with build version 24.

I switched over to using build 23 so I could use the `File Device Explorer` to check my SQLite database files.

When I switched back over to version 24, it started crashing, after giving me the following output at compile:

> uses or overrides a depreciated API

I commented out the `setTime()` method that I used to initialize the time because it had a couple of depreciated methods in it (`setCurrentHour` and `setCurrentTime`).

Unfortunately, it still gives me the compile message:

> uses or overrides a depreciated API

```
    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.time";
    private static final String ARG_DATE = "time";
    private static final String TAG = "TimePickerFragment";
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);

        TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args); // This adds the 'extra'.
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_time, null);

        mTimePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_time_picker);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.time_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    {   // TimePicker lacks an initializer, unlike DatePicker.
                        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTime(date);
                        int initMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                        int initHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                        //setTime(initHour, initMinute);
                    }

                    /*private void setTime(int hour, int minute) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
                            mTimePicker.setMinute(minute);
                        } else {
                            mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
                            mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
                        }
                    }*/


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTime(date);

                        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        int minute = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                        int hour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
                        Date newDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute).getTime();
                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, newDate);
                    }

                    private void sendResult(int resultCode, Date date) {

                        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, date);

                        getTargetFragment()
                                .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
                    }

                })
                .create();
    }

}
```

I expected it to not crash, and I suspect it has something to do with a recent update while using an emulator emulating an earlier version of Android.

Comment: Use logcat to get the message and stack trace of exception caused this crash.

Comment: Okay. I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Miha, I did what you asked and it looks like it's happening after a cursor.close. I put a break at the cursor.close command and it crashes after it goes into fragment manager and then activity thread. ActivityThread.java has some parameters in it that say MemInfoDumpProto that say 'source does not match bytecode.' Dunno if you'd know anything about that. :)

Comment: Follow the stack trace. It should have the answer.